# Preventing bootstrap 4 tabs from showing tab content

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

So I've created an index page with bootstrap 4's tab view, and on each tab I've added an span that contains an X, so the user can close the tab.

However when the X is clicked the tab content still shows, I've found afew questions regarding something similar with bootstrap 3 which lead me onto JQuery

```
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li id="dashboardTab" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="dashboard-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard" role="tab" aria-controls="dashboard" aria-selected="true">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li id="usersTab" class="nav-item" style="display: none;"><a class="nav-link" id="userCreate-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#userCreate" role="tab" aria-controls="userCreate" aria-selected="false">Users<span onclick="onCloseTabButtonClick(0)">X</span></a></li>
                </ul>
```

These are my tabs, nothing special.

```
    function onCloseTabButtonClick(pageNumber) {
        switch (pageNumber) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("usersTab").style.display = "none";
                $('#userCreate-tab').on('click', function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
                break;
        }
    }
```

This is my attempt at stopping the page switch, I'm pretty new to JQuery but from what I understand the `event.preventDefault();` should stop the switch, however it still goes through.

I have tested this by throwing a console.log in there and that fires, so I know my click event does work.

### Update

I tried to pass the close event to the close tab function

```
        <link href="../Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function onCloseTabButtonClick(event, pageNumber) {
                switch (pageNumber) {
                    case 0:
                        document.getElementById("usersTab").style.display = "none";
                        event.preventDefault();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                }
            }
</script>

            <div id="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li id="dashboardTab" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="dashboard-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard" role="tab" aria-controls="dashboard" aria-selected="true">Dashboard</a></li>
                            <li id="usersTab" class="nav-item" style="display: none;"><a class="nav-link" id="userCreate-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#userCreate" role="tab" aria-controls="userCreate" aria-selected="false">Users<span onclick="onCloseTabButtonClick(event, 0)">X</span></a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="dashboard" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dashboard-tab">
                               <%-- Dashboard Page--%>
                            </div>
                            <div id="userCreate" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="userCreate-tab">
                                <%--User Page--%>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**UPDATE 2**
Trying to manage the click and hide event with JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("li.nav-item .tabCloser").click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).parent().hide();
                var idHref=$(this).parent().attr("href");
                $(idHref).removeClass("active");
                console.log('JQuery Fired');
            })
</script>

   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
       <li id="dashboardTab" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="dashboard-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard" role="tab" aria-controls="dashboard" aria-selected="true">Dashboard</a></li>
       <li id="usersTab" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="userCreate-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#userCreate" role="tab" aria-controls="userCreate" aria-selected="false">Users<span class="tabCloser">X</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Remove the Class Active Of container

```
$("li.nav-item .tabCloser").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().hide();
    var idHref=$(this).parent().attr("href");
    $(idHref).removeClass("active");
})
```

try this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/9hzymxs1/1/

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did try this before but I think the switch event fires before my javascript to remove the href does.

Comment: are you removing using jquery??

Comment: No i did it with Javscript, I'll have a look at doing it with JQuery

Comment: cant you remove from html directly?

Comment: So these tabs views are linked to a side bar, When a user for example clicks the Users button for example, the user tab is unhidden, It's at this point my question starts where I want to close the tab when they click the X without switching the content. What I originally tried was setting the href when the Users button was clicked and when the X was clicked I removed it before hiding the tab, but this still switched the content.

Comment: Okay Got it. will be back

Comment: Tried your latest attempt but it only seems to work after the content is switched

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196188/discussion-between-ravi-patel-and-demonic218).

Comment: I think im there finally. Please Check this out. https://jsfiddle.net/9hzymxs1/1/

Comment: The example is just what I am looking for but when I implement it I can't seem to get the JQuery function to fire

Comment: have you updated html as mine?? like my span has different class.

Comment: I've updated my question to show your answer, perhaps I have the JQuery in the incorrect place ?

Comment: try to put it in $(document).ready(function(){ //our logic })

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I changed the event to pass the event data in `onclick="onCloseTabButtonClick(event, 0)"` and to prevent the original click in the handler.

```
<li id="usersTab" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="userCreate-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#userCreate" role="tab" aria-controls="userCreate" aria-selected="false">Users<span onclick="onCloseTabButtonClick(event, 0)">X</span></a></li>
```

```
    function onCloseTabButtonClick(event, pageNumber) {
        switch (pageNumber) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("usersTab").style.display = "none";
                event.preventDefault();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Update:

## Example

```js
    function onCloseTabButtonClick(event, pageNumber) {
        switch (pageNumber) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById("usersTab").style.display = "none";
                event.preventDefault();
                break;
        }
    }
```

```css
@import 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li id="dashboardTab" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="dashboard-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard" role="tab" aria-controls="dashboard" aria-selected="true">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li id="usersTab" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="userCreate-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#userCreate" role="tab" aria-controls="userCreate" aria-selected="false">Users<span onclick="onCloseTabButtonClick(event, 0)">X</span></a></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the content still switches when the X is clicked.

Comment: I have added the working example (press User to switch to tab, press X to close it without switching).

Comment: I've tried using your imports instead thinking it was that, but i still had the same results. I've updated the question with what i currently have

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to provide more details about your case because I think that my code snippet works. I have checked your updated example, and after removing `display: none` for the users tab and adding my JavaScript function, it works correctly.

Comment: I removed the display none and I still have the same issue unfortunately. So for a fuller picture, When the user opens the app, the Dashboard app is the only one visible, there is a side bar with afew buttons, linking to different pages. When a user clicks a button, the related tab is set to display:block, that way a user can view multiple pages in a single page. This now brings me to my question, I want the user to be able to close the tab when they are done on the page, but with it switching when the tab is hidden it sort of breaks the effect. I hope this helps ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:
HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li id="dashboardTab" class="nav-item" style="display: none;"><a class="nav-link active" id="dashboard-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard" role="tab" aria-controls="dashboard" aria-selected="true">Dashboard</a><span class="x-close">X</span></li>
  <li id="usersTab" class="nav-item" style="display: none;"><a class="nav-link" id="userCreate-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#userCreate" role="tab" aria-controls="userCreate" aria-selected="false">Users</a><span class="x-close">X</span></li>
</ul>
<div class="show-all">show all</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show-all").click(function() {
    $("li").show();
  });
  $(".x-close").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("li").hide();
  });
});
```

In this code there is a `div` with class `show-all`. Clicking it causes showing of all `li` elements on the page. 
`span` elements have class `x-close`. Clicking it hides closest element `li`.
See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksiger/cgbkt5yu/10/)

Comment: I can't seem to get the JQuery function to fire with this attempt. I've got a console.log in it to double check and still nothing.

Comment: Asside from a missing favicon, no there are no errors in the console